# Event Trigger Object for AWS Cognito User Pools

Tags: node.js, amazon-web-services, aws-lambda, amazon-cognito

I would like to make a custom verification message for newly registered users in my AWS Cognito User Pool

To do so, I am trying to associate a Lamda function with a "Custom message" trigger.

However, I am not able to find the exact format of the custom message event, to be able to make my lambda function.

The lambda function that I came up with is

```
 exports.handler = function(event, context) {
    // 
    if(event.userPoolId === "us-east-t9....") {

        // Identify why was this function invoked
        if(event.triggerSource === "RegisterUser") {
            // This Lambda function was invoked because a new user signed up to the user-pool "theRequiredUserPool"
            // Ensure that your message contains event.request.codeParameter, this is the place holder for code that will be sent.
                        var link = "https://.....confirm_user.html?username="+ event.userName + "&code=" + event.request.codeParameter;
            var message = "Thank you for signing up. Your confirmation code is " + event.request.codeParameter;
            message+= " Click <a href='"+link+"'>here to finish your registatration!";
            event.response.emailSubject = "Welcome to the service";
            event.response.emailMessage = message;

        }
        // Create custom message for other events
    }
    // Customize messages for other user pools


    // Return result to Cognito
    context.done(null, event);
}
```

When I "test" my function in the Lambda console, it works, but that is because I am testing it against my own event object that I created, based on the only clue I could find in the documentation:

```
{  "version": 1,
  "triggerSource": "RegisterUser/ResendCode/ForgotPassword/VerifyUserAttribute",
  "region": "<region>",
  "userPoolId": "<userPoolId>",
  "userName": "<userName>",
  "callerContext": {
      "awsSdk": "<calling aws sdk with version>",
      "clientId": "<apps client id>",
      ...
  },
  "request": {
      "userAttributes": {
          "phone_verified": true/false,
          "email_verified": true/false,
          ... (all custom attributes)
      },
      "codeParameter": "{code}"
  },
  "response": {
      "smsMessage": "<custom message to be sent in the message with code parameter>"
      "emailMessage": "<custom message to be sent in the message with code parameter>"
      "emailSubject": "<custom email subject>"
  }
}
```

from https://docs.aws.amazon.com/cognito/latest/developerguide/cognito-user-identity-pools-working-with-aws-lambda-triggers.html

I need something more solid than that. I am not able to get my function to work and I don't know where to start. How can I implement a lambda function if I don't know what to expect in the event object? Is there any specification out there for the "Custom Message" event?

UPDATE:
Now that Amazon User Pool's are out of beta, since July 29, 2016, I am no longer having this problem.

Comment: You could use `console.log()` to log the `event` attribute and check its structure in CloudWatch. Do you know if the lambda is even called? The "monitoring" tab in Lambda should help you to see that.

Comment: That's a good idea.@AlexisN-o And no, it doesn't look like the lambda is even called. :-(

Answer (score 0):

Seems like there was an error in the previous documentation. Can you please try using triggerSource name as "CustomMessage_SignUp". You can also check the updated docs for the example.